# Allow only one radiobutton to be selected using RadioButtonFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a bound model for my view which has a checkbox for each User Region and there is one column for DefaultRegion for user. DefaulRegion will be Radio button as only one default region is possible for a user.

I have this code in my view -

```
@for (int i = 0; i < @Model.UserRegions.Count(); i++)
 {
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserRegions[i].IsActive, Model.UserRegions[i].RegionName)
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserRegions[i].RegionId)
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.UserRegions[i].IsActive)
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UserRegions[i].DefaultRegion, Model.UserRegions[i].RegionId)
}
```

My model looks like -

```
public class UserRegion
{
     public int RegionId { get; set; }
     public string RegionName { get; set; }
     public bool IsActive { get; set; }
     public string DefaultRegion { get; set; }
}
```

The code to fetch the data in controller looks like -

```
var usrRegions = (from r in db.REGIONs.Where(r => r.ACTIVE_INDICATOR == "Y")
                    join ur in db.USER_REGION.Where(u => u.USER_ID == userInfo.user.USER_ID) on r.REGION_ID equals ur.REGION_ID into urs
                   from ur in urs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select new UserRegion()
                   {                                      
                      RegionId = r.REGION_ID,
                      RegionName = r.REGION_NAME,
                      IsActive = (ur.USER_ID != null),
                      efaultRegion = (ur.DEFAULT_USER_REGION_INDICATOR != null?"D":"N")
                                  }).ToList();

                userInfo.UserRegions = usrRegions;
```

This shows the check box and radio button correctly but allows to select multiple radio buttons. I understand, that I should assign GroupName somehow so that it considers them in the same group and unselects all radio when a new radio button is selected. But I am not able to figure out this, keeping check box in bound mode.

Any help in this matter is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make sure that all the radio buttons has the same name. This will make it like a radio button group where only one can be selected.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < @Model.UserRegions.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserRegions[i].IsActive, Model.UserRegions[i].RegionName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserRegions[i].RegionId)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.UserRegions[i].IsActive)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UserRegions[i].DefaultRegion, 
                           Model.UserRegions[i].RegionId, new { @Name = "SelectedRegion" })

}
```

Now for model binding to work for the radio button selection, make sure you have a property in your view model with the same name (`SelectedRegion`)

```
public class UserInfoViewModel
{
  public List<UserRegion> UserRegions {set;get;}
  public string SelectedRegion {set;get;}
}
```